# Mysql select sum from two table using join

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get the value of balance from two tables policies and payments. MySQL code below:

```
SELECT Sum(policy.premium)                                                   AS 
       `total` 
       , 
       (SELECT Sum(payments.amount) 
        FROM   payments 
        WHERE  ( payments.date_paid BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-31' )) AS 
       `paid` 
FROM   `policy` 
       LEFT JOIN payments 
              ON policy.code = payments.code 
WHERE  ( policy.st BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-31' ) 
       AND policy.trn_type = 0
```

paid column returns give null, and how can I get the difference between total and paid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the 2 values like this:

```
select t.total, coalesce(t.paid, 0) paid, (t.total - coalesce(t.paid, 0)) diff from (
  select 
    (select sum(premium) from policy where st between '2019-03-01' and '2019-03-31' and policy.trn_type=0) total,
    (select sum(amount) from payments where date_paid between '2019-03-01' and '2019-03-31') paid
) t
```

Comment: (select sum(premium) from policy where st between '2019-03-01' and '2019-03-31' and policy.trn_type=0) and select sum(amount) from payments where date_paid between '2019-03-01' and '2019-03-31'  works but  select t.total, t.paid, (t.total - t.paid) diff from (
  select 
    (select sum(premium) from policy where st between '2019-03-01' and '2019-03-31' and policy.trn_type=0) total
    (select sum(amount) from payments where date_paid between '2019-03-01' and '2019-03-31') paid
) t   gives near error (select sum(amount) from payments where date_paid between '2019-03-01' and '2019-03-31') pa

Comment: am getting syntax error near (select sum(amount) from payments where date_paid between '2019-03-01' and '2019-03-31') pa

Comment: if paid is null diff also returns null even it there is total, e.g. total =1500 paid = null diff = null, how do i correct this? bal should also be 1500

Answer (score 0):

Paid column is just this part:

```
SELECT SUM(payments.amount) 
FROM payments 
WHERE payments.date_paid BETWEEN '2019-03-01' AND '2019-03-31'
```

If it returns null, check first what you have in your data

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it returned null because it was out of date range, i changed the dates and it worked, however how do i get the difference between total and paid?